# Tensorflow summary and plot_model with multiple inputs/outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For the following minimal example, I have several questions about the `summary` and `plot_model` results.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

input_1 = Input(shape=(None, 1), batch_size=1, name='x')
input_2 = Input(shape=(2_000, 1), batch_size=1, name='y')
dense_1 = Dense(14, name='D1', input_shape=(None, 1))
dense_2 = Dense(14, name='D2')
diff = Lambda(lambda xy: xy[0] - xy[1], name='diff')

temp_1 = dense_1(input_1)
temp_2 = dense_1(input_2)

temp_3 = diff([temp_1, temp_2])
out = dense_2(temp_3)

model = Model({'x': input_1, 'y': input_2}, out)
model.summary()
plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

The summary is:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 x (InputLayer)                 [(1, None, 1)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 y (InputLayer)                 [(1, 2000, 1)]       0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 D1 (Dense)                     multiple             28          ['x[0][0]',                      
                                                                  'y[0][0]']                      
                                                                                                  
 diff (Lambda)                  (1, 2000, 14)        0           ['D1[0][0]',                     
                                                                  'D1[1][0]']                     
                                                                                                  
 D2 (Dense)                     (1, 2000, 14)        210         ['diff[0][0]']                   
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 238
Trainable params: 238
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

My questions about this are:

- Why the `[0][0]` in the Connected to column? I guess the first element counts which of the inputs that went into e.g. D1 then become connected to the current layer, e.g. diff, hence why there's a `D1[0]` and a `D1[1]` standing for x and y? But why the second `[0]`?
- The `multiple` in `D1`'s output shape must be because multiple inputs are passed to it and so multiple outputs come out. Is there any way to reduce this back to `(1, None, 1)`, since that describes both inputs? Or to show a list here?

Finally the `plot_model` gives:

[image]

Same question about `D1`'s input and output shapes here.

Also, I would have liked to see 2 arrows out of `D1` as that's what happens, maybe even with different colors corresponding to colors of the arrows going in.

Is any of this possible without a lot of work? My actual model is much more complicated, so it'd be really nice to have more informative summaries and plots.